# How to store large Twitter profile ids in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I need to store follower of follower of few users. The Twitter `followers/ids` gives a list of `id` and not `id_str`. I am storing the whole list of ids returned by api in a list. Then for each id I am finding the follower list. Whenever I use large ids to find their follower list I get the error `Error: Sorry, that page does not exist`. I have tried to convert the ids into string but still the error persists. I must be missing something. I am using the [Twit library](https://github.com/ttezel/twit).

Here is the script where I collect follower list of few user .

```
// store in mongoDB
var storeUserFollowerList = function ( screenName, followerList ) {
twitter_profile.update ({ screen_name : screenName }, {
        follower_list : followerList
} , function ( err, doc ) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.log ( err );
        console.log ( ' Error while updating ');
    } else {
        console.log ( 'Successfull updation ');
        //console.log ( followerList );
    }
});
}
var storeUserFollowerList = function ( screenName, followerList ) {
twitter_profile.update ({ screen_name : screenName }, {
        follower_list : followerList
} , function ( err, doc ) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.log ( err );
        console.log ( ' Error while updating ');
    } else {
        console.log ( 'Successfull updation ');
        //console.log ( followerList );
    }
});
}

var getUserFollowerList = function ( screenName, nextCursor, callback ) {
twits.get ( 'followers/ids', { screen_name : screenName,
                                        cursor : nextCursor }, 
                        function ( err, data, response ) {
    //console.log (data);
    if ( err ) {
        console.log ( err + ' for ' + screenName );
    } else {
        callback ( screenName, data['ids'] );
        //console.log ( data['ids'] )
        if( data["next_cursor_str"] != "0" ) {
            getUserFollowerList ( screenName, data["next_cursor_str"], callback );
        }
    }
});
}

var getUsers = function ( callback ) {
screenNames.forEach ( function ( screenName ) {
    /*
    By default, an API endpoint that supports cursoring will assume 
    -1 was passed as cursor if you do not provide one
    */
    callback ( screenName, "-1", storeUserFollowerList ); 
});
}
```

Here is how I get follower list of those followers

```
var getFollowerListOfFollowers = function( followerList, i ) {
// if current follower is not in db then search for its follower list and update db
twitter_profile.find ( { id : followerList[i] }, function ( err, dbData ) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.log ( err );
    } else  {
        if ( dbData.length > 0 ) {
                console.log ( ' we have this user ... ignore ');
                getFollowerListOfFollowers ( followerList, ++i );
        } else {
            get_follower_list ( ' ' + followerList[i], enter_in_db );
            getFollowerListOfFollowers ( followerList, ++i );
        }
    }
});
}

var getFollowerOfFollowers = function () {
screenNames.forEach ( function ( screenName ) {
    twitter_profile.find ( { screen_name : screenName }, 
                                        function ( err, dbData ) {
        if ( err ) {
            console.log ( err );
        } else {
            if ( dbData.length > 0 ) {
                // get follower list for each follower of this user 
                getFollowerListOfFollowers ( dbData[0]['follower_list'], 0 );
                //console.log ( dbData[0]['follower_list'] );
            } else {
                console.log ( ' Data not found in DB ');
            }
        }
    });
});
}
```

Finally

```
var enterInDB = function ( id, followerList ) {
new twitter_profile ( {
    _id:    id,
    id:     id,
    follower_list:  followerList
}).save (function ( err, doc ) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.log ( err );
    } else {
        console.log ( ' -----------Entered Profile into database------------- ');
    }
});
}

var getFollowerList = function ( id, callback ) {
twits.get ( 'followers/ids', { id : id }, function ( err, data, response ) {
    //console.log (data);
    if ( err ) {
        console.log ( err + ' for ' + id );
    } else {
        callback ( id, ""+data['ids'] );
        //console.log ( data['ids'] )
    }
});
}
```

Getting errors for ids like `730292604265435100` , `702941284181237800`

Comment: Could you provide your code and a sample id which leads to the error? You will get an answer much faster this way ;)

Comment: @KRONWALLED right ! added !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer. My day was kinda busy.

I tried to look up these ids via the Twitter API console and got the same results you mentioned.

After trying various api methods for those ids (with everyone failing) I decided to lookup the profile on Twitter itself.

This failed too. So I looked for a random profile with few followers but one follower in this id range.

I found one! He had a follower with the id `728920217020158000`. If you look this id up through the api you will see there are no results because the id is invalid.

I noticed that the id_str field showed another id. If you look for the id `728920217020157955` through the api you will find his profile.

So you have to tell `twit` to return the stringified ids to you also.

I don't have `twit` installed right now so you could try it this way

```
twits.get ( 'followers/ids', { id : id, stringify_ids : true }
    //console.log (data);
    if ( err ) {
        console.log ( err + ' for ' + id );
    } else {
        callback ( id, ""+data['ids'] );
        //console.log ( data['ids'] )
    }
});
```

For more information about this endpoint visit [Twitter API Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids)

Comment: thanks man! you are a life saver :) ! silly of me not to read the documentation tho !